# WPF StringFormat={}{0:N} Error "Expected '"

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008-sp1, string-formatting

I'm getting an error in VS 2008 SP1 with WPF using the stringformat binding, is there an inherent problem with wpf in vs 2008?

Error 1 Expected ' ConstituentCrossrateGridControl.xaml 70 141 PriceViewWpfLibrary

Comment: I have been involved in a number of WPF projects in VS 2008 (SP1) and have not encountered an "inherent" problem with WPF in VS 2008.

Answer (score 7):

As the error message suggests, try wrapping your StringFormat value in single quotes. For example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0:N}'}" />
```

Comment: But that is invalid XAML:  A markup extension may not include quotes of any kind.  You always get the exception "Names and Values in a markup extension cannot contain quotes."

Therefore his problem is something else.

Comment: Maybe, but wrapping the StringFormat value in single quotes works fine for me, and I learned it from reading example code from Microsoft (though I don't remember where specifically).

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2008 IDE's XAML syntax parser has several bugs where it complains that certain valid XAML is invalid.

Does this method of escaping work for you?

```
StringFormat=\{0:N\}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can only be used when the target property is of type String.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are opening your attribute value using a single quote but closing it using a double-quote.  But that is only a guess.

Please post the referenced line of code so we can give you better feedback.